# Pandas Dataframe showing duplicates by multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DF with 3m rows and 16 columns. I have been trying to find duplicates based on certain columns only. Hence I want to subset the data where these rows have the exact same value in the 6 columns. I want to keep all rows based on the duplicates.

```
pp19952017[pp19952017.duplicated(subset=['Postcode', 'Property Type','Street','Town/City', 'District', 'County'],keep=False)]
```

Edit:
Here is an example of mostly like a single property but won't show up with show duplicates because not every column is the same and a few cells are different. I want to have a list of duplicates so I can see how the same properties have increase in price.

`15, ARMINGER ROAD, LONDON, HAMMERSMITH AND FULHAM, W12 7BA, GREATER LONDON`

and

`15, ARMINGER ROAD, LONDON, LONDON, HAMMERSMITH AND FULHAM, W12 7BA, GREATER LONDON`

Unfortunately, this gives me nearly every line. I've checked manually and there aren't this many duplicates so I'm a bit stuck as to how to find the duplicates. 
As this is data is from 1995 to the present day the way it was recorded changed, so I can only attempt to use this subset to find the duplicates.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Solution**:
I think I found a way to do it. Which is that I concatenated the various columns that were relevant and had repeating data and used that new concatenated column's data to use as a check for duplication. It is a workaround but does what I want.

Comment: We need more details. For instance, if your dataset is individual level data then of course I'd expect most things to be duplicated. Every member of a household will have the same info across those columns. Or even if it's household level data, if there are only a few unique property types, I'd assume that **most** streets would have more than a single house so I'd still expect the dataset to be mostly duplicated at that level.

Comment: Actually, this is the correct method, or you can use `drop_duplicaes` also. You checked manually, did you consider 'whitespace' issues?  Can you create a subset of that data that does not produce the desired results with your coded above?

Comment: Thanks. What is the whitespace issue? I didn't see any whitespaces in any of the cells.

Comment: @ALollz Thanks I think I know what you mean. I'll have a look and see if there is a better way of doing what I am subsetting. I want to find the rows where there is the exact same content as another row. Unfortunately I just realised that it's finding most rows because virtually every data point is repeated somewhere and it's finding duplicates for the individual data points not the 7 columns all together.

Comment: it will find duplicates for all the subset of column that you provided but keep will mark everything as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicated is working as intended. The problem is with the usage. You are passing `keep=False`. It means that all the duplicate records will be marked as duplicate and it will return all the duplicate records.

e.g. (`Adam, 30, NY`), (`Adam, 35, NY`), (`Adam, 30, MA`) and you are doing duplicates based on name & state (`keep = False`) will return 2 rows as it will mark both the rows as duplicate.

if you pass `keep = first`  or `last` it will mark the first or last record as duplicate accordingly and will return only 1 row.

Comment: @Rahul  - What do you think will be the output if the sample data is  (Adam, 30, NY), (Adam, 31, NY), (Adam, 35, NY), ( Adam, 30, MA) with  keep = 'first' or 'last' ? It will be 2 records as it returns the duplicate rows and will mark one of them as non-duplicate.